# Problem in accessing user input value from the input field in SQL query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms, ado.net

I am creating a report using ASP.NET webforms with ADO.NET classes and SQL. On the client side there are 4 input fields for entering 'from date', 'to date', 'product' and 'warranty status' to fetch the desired data from the database, the three input fields are working exactly how I want but the 'warranty status' field is not working.

I have provided the SQL query below but as you see after where clause I gave the parameter 'Canceled' directly and now its working fine but whenever I replace this parameter with 'txtwarranty.value' to use user input parameter in my query, my code does not fetch data.

This is the code I wrote in the `.aspx` file for input field :

```
<div class="form-group row">                                                    
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <select id="slctwarranty" runat="server" name="select" class="js-example-basic-multiple" required="required">
            <option value="-1" selected="selected">Select Warranty </option>
            <option value="1">Canceled</option>
            <option value="2">Registered</option>
            <option value="3">In-Process</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
                                                   
<div id="tableContainer" runat="server" class="dt-responsive table-responsive">
    <input runat="server" id="txtservice" visible="false" />
    <input runat="server" id="txtwarranty" visible="false" />
</div>
```

~sql query

```
where c.warranty_status in ('Canceled') and 
c.FK_Product in (" + txtservice.Value + ") 
and c.RegisteredOn between '"+Convert.ToDateTime(txtfromdate.Value)+"' and '" + Convert.ToDateTime(txttodate.Value) + "' 
, connection_CollectionReport))
```

Comment: *Please* learn for format your code. That SQL Statement is unreadable.

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: You need to format that SQL - we can't read it. Also, textWarrenty has a visible  = false, so there not much of a surprise why using txtwarrenty does not work. And WHY are you using a "in" clause for txtwarretny, should not you be using some colurm = "the txtwarretny value goes here"

Comment: I think you need to do a fair bit more studying: 1. What does `value="1"` in this line of code `<option value="1">Canceled</option>` do? 2. Read [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect?view=netframework-4.8.1) for how to use this control.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as noted, you don't want to use string concatenation WITH user input when building SQL.

Else you wind up with this:

[image]

And it turns out, that while it "seems" to save some efforts in coding?

It does not, since now you dealing with a bunch of extra "'" (single quotes) for text, no quotes for numbers, and quotes for dates. This creates VERY error prone code (let alone the SQL injection issue).

So, a few things:

```
c.FK_Product in (" + txtservice.Value + ")
```

Why does the above use a "IN" clause? Do you expect txtservice to have more then one value? If not, then the above should be:

```
c.FK_Product = @txtService
```

However, it does look like your selection is multi-select. So, we need some code to deal with that.

so, this code is a good starting point:

```
        string strSQL = "my messy SQL";

        string strWhere =
            @" where c.warranty_status = 'Canceled'
            and c.RegisteredOn between @dtStart and @dtEnd
            and c.FK_Product = @service
            ORDER BY Readyfordelverydate DESC;";

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL + strWhere);
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@dtStart", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtfromdate.Value;
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@dtEnd", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txttodate.Value;
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@service", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtservice.Value;

        DataTable dt = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);
```

And in my application wide General class, I have this re-usable routine:

```
    public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

So above is a good starting point. As you can see, the code is far more easy to deal with the quotes etc.

However, since warranty status looks to be multiple values? Then you need to deal with that.

You can't use a "in clause" with an @ SQL parameter.

However, you still can use/have/enjoy parameter safe code, even with multiple values.